# Object key optional with typescript — but being able to call it

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following `interfaces` declared

```
export interface User {
  ...
  first: string;
  ...
}

export interface UserDataState {
  credentials: User | {};
  ..
}
```

In my react component, I want to be able to access the `first` in the `UserDataState` like this:

```
const userData = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.credentials);

Welcome, { userData.first }
```

However I'm getting this error

```
Property 'first' does not exist on type '{} | User'.
```

So I tried the following:

```
let userFirst = '';

if (userData.hasOwnProperty('first')) {
  userFirst = userData.first;
}

...

return ( <span>{userFirst}</span>)
```

and..

```
return ( {userData && userData.first && (<span>{userData.first}</span>)})
```

I don't want to make the user first optional and I need to be able to return an empty object to as the credentials. This is very much annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use [optional chaning](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining).

For example, in your case, I would do the following:

```
export interface UserDataState {
  credentials: User | undefined;
}
```

To access `first` from `crendentials` from `state` (suppose `state` is nullable), instead of doing:

```
state && state.credentials && state.credentials.first
```

You just need to use the optional chaining operator `?.`

```
state?.credentials?.first
```

By doing this you won't compromise the type safety of your codebase with explicit casting, for example casting to `any`.

This idiom is pretty standard with Typescript 3.7 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with

```
const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.credentials);
const userData: any = user;

// or this works to
import { User as UserType } from '../types';
const userData: { first?: UserType['first'] } = user;
```

Not sure if this is best practice though, if anyone has a better method would love to hear it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, so basically what you are doing is enforcing the type that it is going to be a `User` type:

```js
const userData = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.credentials) as User;
```